# Splitting cells into two using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, split, itext, pdfptable

I'm trying to generate a PDF file using iTextSharp, and I've wrote this code so far:

```
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4,50,50,120,40);


        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path+"\\Invoices\\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;


        table.DefaultCell.HasBorder(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, Phrase = new Phrase("The text on the left goes here", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial",10.00f,iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)), BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE, BorderWidth = 0 });
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER, Phrase = new Phrase("Contact us\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10.00f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD | iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE)), BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE, BorderWidth = 0 });

        // table.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT, Phrase = new Phrase("Email\nPhone2\nPhone1\nFax\nCell", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10.00f, BaseColor.BLACK)), BorderColor = BaseColor.WHITE, BorderWidth = 0 });

        doc.Open();
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Text above cells goes here\n ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8.0f, BaseColor.BLACK));

        doc.Add(p2);

        doc.Add(table);
        doc.Close();
```

I'm trying to create an output like this:

```
The text above the cells

The text on the left goes here                      **Contact us**
                                                      Email      l@test.com
                                                      Phone2     01234567890
                                                      Phone1     01234567890
                                                      Fax        01234567890
                                                      Cell       01234567890
```

The text Contact us has to stay bolded and underline while the text email, phone2,1 needs to be just regular Arial 10 font...

Can I somehow split this cell into two parts and say elements on the left side align to left and in 2nd cell align to left?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You're looking for a cell that spans multiple columns. Have a look at some  of these examples for complex tables (some are in java, but C# should have the same methods, just slightly different signature) : http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-table-which-cells-have-different-widths ,  http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-set-table-display , http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/tables/how-create-nested-column

Comment: @Samuel ty for that, I've solved the issue yesterday by doing that. Cheers :)